# Would using inheritance improve speed and maintainability of similar queries?

Tags: mysql, sql, inheritance, mysql-workbench, dashboard

**Here is my situation:**

1. I have 4 queries running on a php dashboard showing asynchronous data.
2. All 4 queries are fired simultaneously and on demand throughout the
   day.
3. Each query joins around 3-5 tables (applying unique where
   conditions depending on the query).
4. All 4 queries share 2 or 3 of the same tables...thus there is a lot
   of  repeated code between the 4 queries.
5. Each table can have up to 6 columns, hundreds of millions of rows,
   and up to 5gigs of data total
6. Queries should return in under 30 seconds when NOT relying on cache,
   and a couple seconds or less when they can use the cache

**My question is:**

Would it be possible/beneficial to apply inheritance to optimize queries? I could have a view that is a query for the 2-3 common tables all 4 of my main queries depend on, and then have 4 smaller queries that just apply their unique extra tables and conditions?

**Pros:**

1. It would be easier to maintain the queries down the road because I
   could just update the one view instead of repeatedly making changes
   in all 4 queries
2. It might be faster because that one stored procedure/view would end up being
   cached most of the time

**Cons:**

1. Now instead of running 4 queries I would essentially be running 8
   queries (since every time you run a query that calls the view/stored
   procedure you have to run that one too)
2. Using the view might cause me to pull tons of extra data for every
   query

**Here's an example of two similar queries:**

```
SELECT
    SUM(visitor_cart_items.quantity * (TRIM(REPLACE(visitor_cart_items.price, '$', '')) + 0.0)) 
FROM
    (SELECT DISTINCT
           visitor_cart_items.id,
           visitor_cart_items.price,
           visitor_cart_items.quantity
    FROM
        messages_sent
        JOIN session_guid ON session_guid.visitor_forms_id = messages_sent.visitor_forms_id
        JOIN session_guid sessions ON sessions.session_guid = session_guid.session_guid
        JOIN visitor_cart_items ON visitor_cart_items.cart_id = sessions.visitor_forms_id

    WHERE
        sessions.status_type_id = 1
        AND sessions.website_id = 7
        AND messages_sent.status_id = 1
        AND sessions.updated_timestamp BETWEEN '2015-05-01' AND '2015-05-08') visitor_cart_items;
```

and

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(DISTINCT sessions.visitor_forms_id) all_saves
FROM
    messages_sent
    JOIN session_guid ON session_guid.visitor_forms_id = messages_sent.visitor_forms_id
    JOIN session_guid sessions ON sessions.session_guid = session_guid.session_guid
    JOIN visitor_forms ON visitor_forms.id = sessions.visitor_forms_id
WHERE
    sessions.status_type_id = 1
    AND sessions.website_id = 7
    AND visitor_forms.form_type_id = 1 #1 for forms, 2 for carts
    AND sessions.updated_timestamp BETWEEN '2015-05-01' AND '2015-05-08';
```

Comment: I think I recall reading that MySQL can be somewhat smart when using VIEWs in querys, so it won't necessarily be executing 8 queries (nor will the VIEW data always be cached, especially if it is large). However, VIEWs do complicate things, and their usefulness and/or drawbacks in this scenario could vary greatly on the context they are used.

Comment: Also, I don't think it would make it easier down the road as you would need to factor in that interaction whenever you wanted to change the VIEW.

Answer (score 0):

My experience has been that trying to apply inheritance/OO style thinking at the database level is a very bad thing to do.

In general, simpler views tend to be OK... the query optimizers on different DBMS's are good at 'boiling down' the views and giving you good performance.

However, when you get more complicated and start using views with aggregate functions, user-defined functions and other errata to achieve code reuse, it usually comes at huge I/O and query plan expense. We went down that road and had to rip out those things and retreat. It's just not worth it in my opinion. Code duplication is a better problem to have than a horrendous query plan.